# Software engineering: friend is a user on a UML model

Tags: uml

I'm developing a software where a user can be a friend of another user. Is friend a class on a UML model?

I think friend is a user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend is a relationship between two users. See [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/rreltyp.html) list of relationship types, perhaps one of them will be right for what you are trying to model.